# Using sklearn logistic regression on new text when CountVectorizer has been used - need same number of sparse matrix features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tokenize

I have a logistic regression that I've trained on some data using sklearn and CountVectorizer in the following way:

```
vect= CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3), binary =True, min_df=250, stop_words = 'english')
X = vect.fit_transform(data['text'].values)
y = data['label']

logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1, penalty='l1')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

model = logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
joblib.dump(model, 'log_reg_model.pkl')
```

I would like to use to load the same model into another python file and use it to evaluate text found in a different context. However, when I try to use CountVectorizer in the second context, because I am vectorizing a different set of text, the sparse matrix created has a different number of features.

```
model = joblib.load('log_reg_model.pkl') 

if DEBUG:
    sys.stdin = open('test.tsv', 'r')

data = DataFrame(columns = ['text'])

for line in sys.stdin:
    fields = line.split('\t')
    data.loc[len(data)+1]=[fields[0]]

vect= CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3), binary =True, stop_words = 'english')
text = vect.fit_transform(data['text'].values)
prediction = model.predict(text)

ValueError: X has 131690 features per sample; expecting 4128
```

Does anyone know how to get around this? I basically need to "vectorize" the new text using the same sparse matrix as I used originally.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by saving the features of the first Vectorizer, and then using them as the vocabulary argument of the second. E.g.,

```
feature_list = vect.get_feature_names()
joblib.dump(feature_list, 'vocabulary.pkl')
```

And then

```
vocabulary = joblib.load('vocabulary.pkl') 
vect= CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3), binary =True, stop_words = 'english', vocabulary = vocabulary)
```